# How to disable ADT graphical layout editor?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

How to disable Eclipse ADT graphical layout editor?

In its current state it causes long pauses when switching between XML files rendering Eclipse ADT unusable without a restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must go to the Preferences -> General- >Editors->File Associations and in the Associated editors section remove the Android Layout Editor for *.XML extension.

Close Eclipse and restart. Otherwise this will not work.